# unexpected result from listp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, predicate

I have a struct spider:

```
(defstruct spider omegas values k)
```

And an instance *spider*:

```
(set '*spider* (make-spider
  :omegas '()
  :values (list *input*)
  :k '(#'omegashift #'dec #'dupval '((0 . #'dec) (1 . #'inc) (2 . #'dec)))))
```

But when I run the expression: `(listp (car (spider-k *spider*))` on Emacs and SBCL (and SLIME is involved but I'm not sure what it is.)
The REPL returns `T`. This is obviously confusing as `(car (spider-k *spider*)` correctly returns `#'OMEGASHIFT` and `(listp (function OMEGASHIFT))` properly returns `NIL`.

Why is `(listp (car (spider-k *spider*))` true? Shouldn't it be false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#'omegashift` is a reader-macro that expands to the list `(function omegashift)`.

When you evaluate `(function omegashift)` you get a function, but you're not evaluating it because you quoted the list. So you're just getting the list that the reader-macro expands to.

You'd see the same thing if you did `(listp (car '('foo)))`. `'foo` expands to the list `(quote foo)`. This evaluates to the symbol `foo`, but the quote before the list prevents evaluation.

To get functions instead of lists, you need to evaluate the function expressions. You can do this by calling the function `list` rather than quoting a list.

```
(setq *spider* (make-spider
  :omegas '()
  :values (list *input*)
  :k (list #'omegashift #'dec #'dupval (list (cons 0  #'dec) (cons 1  #'inc) (cons 2  #'dec)))))
```

You can also use backquote to simplify this:

```
(setq *spider* (make-spider
  :omegas '()
  :values (list *input*)
  :k `(,#'omegashift ,#'dec ,#'dupval '((0 . ,#'dec) (1 . ,#'inc) (2 . ,#'dec)))))
```

Inside a backquoted expression, you use comma to mark the sub-expressions that you want to evaluate.

BTW, you should use `setq` to assign variables, not `set` with a quoted symbol. They're equivalent for global variables, but you can't use `set` with a local variable.

Comment: I have been not using setq because when I do SBCL complains about undefined variables

Comment: Use `defvar` to declare global variables then it won't complain.